# Why in scapy packet.payload.proto == 17 is UDP and packet.payload.proto ==6 TCP?

Tags: python, scapy

I saw this code in github.
I dont uderstand why packet.payload.proto == 17 is UDP and  packet.payload.proto ==6  TCP.

packets = scapy.all.rdpcap('data/dns.cap')

for packet in packets:
    print('----------')
    print('src_mac: {0}'.format(packet.src))
    print('dst_mac: {0}'.format(packet.dst))

```
ip = packet.payload
print('src_ip: {0}'.format(ip.src))
print('dst_ip: {0}'.format(ip.dst))

if ip.proto == 17:
    udp = ip.payload
    print('udp_sport: {0}'.format(udp.sport))
    print('udp_dport: {0}'.format(udp.dport))

if ip.proto == 6:
    tcp = ip.payload
    print('tcp_sport: {0}'.format(tcp.sport))
    print('tcp_dport: {0}'.format(tcp.dport))

print('----------\n')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [the IANA says so](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml).

> ```
>  ...
> 6     TCP     Transmission Control        [RFC793]
>  ...
> 17    UDP     User Datagram               [RFC768][Jon_Postel]
>  ...
> ```

Comment: What is packet.payload?

Comment: Other than the payload of the packet?

Comment: I dont understand what payload is! Could you explain, please?

Comment: You have an IP packet. And inside that packet you have the TCP/UDP/etc. packet. That packet-within-a-packet is the [payload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Ignacio is correct.  The RFCs and IANA designate those values.

As for what a payload is, that is relative to what packet (PDU more specifically) layer you are talking about.

Take the following example:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  IP         |  TCP       |   HTTP                           |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

HTTP is the payload of TCP, and (TCP + HTTP) is the payload of IP.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  IP         |  TCP       |   Payload                        |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

and

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  IP         |  Payload                                      |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header Shows the layout of an IP header.  Protocol is one of those fields.  When the protocol (`ip.proto`) is 6, per RFC the payload of the IP traffic is TCP.  When it is 17, the payload is UDP.

Some protocols (like IP) have a field that enumerates what type their child payload is.  Others don't.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!